# In minecraft bedrock(1.14.30), is it possible to detect if a player is standing still, and then give them a potion effect if they are?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a little game for me and my friends to play, but the one part I can't seem to figure out is the question posed in the title. I want to give a player that stands still withering to promote people to keep moving.

Comment: You can't just check the `Motion` NBT tag like in MCJava, but maybe this can be done with scoreboards. I don't know if they work the same as in MCJava. And even if they do, you need one for running, one for jumping, one for gliding, etc. and check if they all remain 0 at the tick after you've last reset them.

Comment: @FabianRöling `dummy` is the only criterion supported in BE, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Run /setblock to set a unique block under the player. Then after your time limit perform an execute/detect variant which conditionally gives the /effect you need. Be sure to /setblock the unique block back to something else afterward.